# handling rails + postgres and timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

I have an application which uses many different timezones... it sets them in a controller and they change depending on the user.  All the times are stored in UTC without a timestamp etc.

My understanding is this is the normal way for Rails to handle timezones.  This works fine 99% of the time until i need to do something directly with Postgres then the Timezone becomes a problem.

For example this query is completely wrong except for GMT, for example in Central Time Zone, depending on the hour set, it gets the wrong day:

```
Events.where("EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at)", Date.today.wday)
```

Where I'm trying to find all the dates that fall on a certain day.

I'm trying to do something like this.  I don't need to search between timezones (they won't be mixed), but I do need to specify the timezone if it's not UTC to get correct results.

```
User.events.where("EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at AT TIME ZONE ?) = ?", 'UTC', Date.today.wday)
```

But I'm not sure how to use `Time.zone` to give me something that will work with TIME ZONE in Postgres.

Time.zone.tzinfo sometimes works... Postgres will work with 'Europe/Warsaw' but Rails returns 'Europe - Warsaw'

In general I'm not having much luck with timezones, any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone else has a better overall solution, but what you need for the particular query is

```
Time.zone.tzinfo.identifier
```

Or, in your example:

```
User.events.where("EXTRACT(dow FROM start_at AT TIME ZONE ?) = ?", Time.zone.tzinfo.identifier, Date.today.wday)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Ruby [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.github.io/) gem directly, instead of using Rails [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).

Alternatively, use the `MAPPING` constant, as shown in the [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) documentation, which will take you from a Rails time zone key back to the standard IANA time zone identifier used by Postgres and others.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Johnson suggested use TZInfo gem directly. This way you can get the correctly formatted time zone identifiers you need to query with PostgreSQL.

For example if you use:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers
```

This will return an array of correct IANA/Olson time zone identifiers. In other words you will get the correct 'Europe/Warsaw' NOT 'Europe - Warsaw'.